# Arquillian with Wildfly

Tags: wildfly, jboss-arquillian

I try to use Arquillian with WildFly 8.1.0 Final version for tests. The server, which is test container starts, beans are loaded, but the tests (even the simplest) don't passed.

This is the console log:

```
ERROR [io.undertow.request] UT005023: Exception handling request to /test/ArquillianServletRunner: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.TestResult.setEnd(J)V
at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.container.JUnitTestRunner.execute(JUnitTestRunner.java:84) [arquillian-junit.jar:]
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.executeTest(ServletTestRunner.java:160) [arquillian-protocol.jar:]
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.execute(ServletTestRunner.java:126) [arquillian-protocol.jar:]
at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.doGet(ServletTestRunner.java:90) [arquillian-protocol.jar:]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_91]
```

My test:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class GeneratorTest {

public GeneratorTest() {
}

@Deployment
public static Archive<?> createDeployment(){
      WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war");
      war.addClass(SessionHandler.class)
         .addClass(Generator.class)
         .addClass(TestResult.class);
     return war;
    }

@Inject
SessionHandler sessionHandler;

@Inject
Generator Generator;

@Test
public void testGenerateValue() {
    assertTrue(true);
}
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
     </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-embedded</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-embedded</artifactId>
        <version>8.1.0.Final</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.core</groupId>
       <artifactId>arquillian-core-impl-base</artifactId>
       <version>1.1.11.Final</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>  
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3.Final</version>  
        <scope>test</scope>  
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
       <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
       <type>pom</type>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-core-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-drone-bom</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-test-impl-base</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-test-spi</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-container-spi</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-container-test-spi</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>-->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>2.8</version>
             <executions>
                 <execution>
                    <id>unpack</id>
                       <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>unpack</goal>
                       </goals>
                       <configuration>
                           <artifactItems>
                               <artifactItem>
                                   <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
                                   <artifactId>wildfly-dist</artifactId>
                                   <version>8.1.0.Final</version>
                                   <type>zip</type>
                                   <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                                   <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                               </artifactItem>
                           </artifactItems>
                       </configuration>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
        </plugin>
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Fork every test because it will launch a separate AS instance -->
                <forkMode>always</forkMode>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                      <!-- the maven dependency plugin will have already downloaded the server on /target -->
                    <jboss.home>${project.basedir}/target/wildfly-8.1.0.Final</jboss.home>
                    <module.path>${project.basedir}/target/wildfly-8.1.0.Final/modules</module.path>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
                <redirectTestOutputToFile>false</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>        
    </plugins>
</build>

<profiles>
           <profile>
                       <id>arquillian-jbossas-managed</id>
                       <dependencies>
                             <dependency>
                                   <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
                                   <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
                                   <scope>test</scope>
                             </dependency>
                             <dependency>
                                     <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
                                     <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
                                     <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                                     <type>pom</type>
                                     <scope>provided</scope>
                             </dependency>
                             <dependency>
                                   <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
                                   <artifactId>jboss-as-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>
                                   <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
                                  <scope>test</scope>
                              </dependency>
                              <dependency>
                                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
                                    <scope>test</scope>
                              </dependency>
                     </dependencies>
            </profile>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dependencies are all over the place.

- your pom file is leveraging arquillian 1.0.4, 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.1.11.  Please only use one, and preferably 1.1.11 as its much newer, more bug fixes.
- *Wildfly 8 is EE7 ignore prior comment*

Comment: WildFly 8 is a Java EE 7 container.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins is it? Thought that happened in 9, my bad :-)

Comment: Yup :) WildFly 8 was the first Java EE 7 certified container. Both 9 and 10 are also both Java EE 7.